# Open Excel sheet and press Ctrl + Q

Tags: autohotkey

I want to open an excel sheet and press Ctrl + Q to call a macro. However the ctrl+q part is not working. What I've tried so far:

```
run, %A_Desktop%\test.xlsm, %A_Desktop%\
Send {Ctrl Down}{Q}{Ctrl Up}
```

This is not working either:

```
run, %A_Desktop%\test.xlsm, %A_Desktop%\
Send ^{Q}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WinWait` to wait for the window to appear, `WinActivate` and `WinWaitActive` before sending any commands to it:

```
; https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs

; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance
full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

Run, %A_Desktop%\test.xlsm
WinWait, test.xlsm
WinActivate, test.xlsm
WinWaitActive, test.xlsm
Sleep, 300 ; if the program doesn't react immediately after activating
Send {Ctrl Down}q{Ctrl Up}
```

Replace `test.xlsm` with the exact title of the window as shown in Window Spy.

Comment: Shouldn't I give name of title for winwait/activate/waitactive? Like WinWait, "test" or WinActivate, "test" ?

Comment: I don't think window is getting activated so the remaining code is not running

Comment: I think it's some other issue. Like I said in my response to the other user, I'm able to send Ctrl+F or whatever key that is not assigned as a shortcut call to a function.

Comment: Maybe you should run the script as administrator. See the edited answer.

Comment: Small question, what's %scriptfullpath% and ahkpath ? Are they different?

Comment: So scriptfullpath contains the full path to the compiled .exe and ahkpath contains the path to the corresponding .ahk file, am I correct?

Comment: `A_ScriptFullPath` is the full path to the running script (ScriptName`.ahk`) because in this case the script is not compiled. `A_AhkPath` is the full path of the executable `AutoHotkey.exe`.

Comment: You don't have to replace `A_ScriptFullPath` or `A_AhkPath` in the above code. The values of these Built-in Variables are automatically detected by the program.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it. But one question, does that mean I still need Autohotkey installed to run the compiled .exe files?

Comment: A compiled script doesn't need Autohotkey installed to run. https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'send' works too fast, while file is not opened completely. Try '[sleep](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm)' before 'send'.

Comment: I think the problem is soemthing else. I have programmed Ctrl+Q to call a function/macro in my workbook. If I try some other shortcut like Ctrl+F, then it runs just fine. However if I manually press Ctrl+Q after opening excel, the shortcut is working..